# Document variables that are accessed via __get for IDEs

Tags: php, ide

Is there a way to document variables that are accessed via the `__get` magic method in a way that IDEs can recognize their existence and return type?

For instance I want to expose `done` and `helper` via `__get` but also want an IDE like PHPStorm to be able to know that they exist:

```
class Thing
{
    /** @var bool */
    private $done;

    /** @var HelperThing */
    private $helper;

    __get( $name )
    {
        if ( $name === "done" )
            return $done;

        if ( $name === "helper" )
            return $helper;
    }    
}
```

I was trying to avoid using the psudeo-getter approach like `$thing->getHelper()` as I prefer the style of `$thing->helper->someOtherMethod()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@property` tag for magic properties, and `@method` for magic method documentation. These are supported by PHPStorm. See the documentation for [@property](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/property.html) and [@method](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/method.html) for more information.